Use a function from one .astro file in another .astro file
Hola alguien sabe cómo puedo usar mi función setHTMLcontent desde mi layout en el archivo fondo.astro, había buscado que tenía que importarla pero no funcionan las formas que intente, estoy usando astro
Hello, does anyone know how I can use my setHTMLcontent function from my layout in the Fondo.astro file, I had searched that I had to import it but the ways I tried don't work, I'm using astro
Try with import {setHTMLcontent} from "./Layout.astro"

Why don't just move this function to separate file and import it from both wherever you need? Export from astro still under rfc
